# Why is collaborator information of public repositories not publicly available?

Tags: github, github-api

For one of my projects I wanted to collect information regarding the number of collaborators on public repositories in GitHub. I know that the endpoint for this information, can accessed only if you have sufficient rights to that repository (I have tried with REST api). I was hoping to understand why GitHub does not provide  this information of public repositories to everyone?